# google.load custom js

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-ajax-api

I am using [google ajax api](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EU/apis/ajax/documentation/)
How can I load custom js which depends on libs loaded by ajaxapi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a function that inserts the script object into the DOM like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadMyCustomJavaScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://www.example.org/my.js";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

and either use it as `google.setOnLoadCallback`

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABCDEFG" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(loadMyCustomJavaScript);
</script>
```

or, if you want to load it with a specific Google library that you load, as a callback for that method, ie.

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABCDEFG" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("maps", "2");
  google.load("search", "1", {"callback" : loadMyCustomJavaScript});
</script>
```

*Update:* Based on your comment, you could try to use [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) which provides a callback function for the (externally) loaded JavaScript code. According to [HubLog: Google, jQuery and plugin loading](http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001816.html), you may have to use `window.setTimeout` to delay the execution of a function until the script(s) has/have eval'd.

Since jQuery and it's plugins are probably loaded asynchronously, you may need to use unobtrusive JavaScript instead of using jQuery/plugin functions in the HTML code directly.

Comment: Yes I have already tryed using function like your loadMyCustomJavaScript but I need to load jquery plugins and use it but I don't know how when are they loaded.

Comment: Did my update help you? Is there anything else you need to know?